# How to delete rows from three tables - query error

Tags: mysql

I need to delete rows from multiple mysql tables (3). this is my query it show a error but I create this query according to the examples and tutorials.

```
DELETE 
  FROM customers
     , orders
     , order_detail 
 USING customers 
  JOIN orders
  JOIN order_detail 
 WHERE customers.id = orders.customers_id 
   AND orders.id = order_detail.orders_id 
   AND customers.id IN (66,67,68,90,85,81,80,78,76,74,71,118,113,110,149)
```

Comment: nop error is remaining

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE c,o,d
  FROM customers c
  JOIN orders o
    ON o.customers_id = c.id
  JOIN order_detail d
    ON d.orders_id = o.id
 WHERE c.id IN (66,67,68,90,85,81,80,78,76,74,71,118,113,110,149)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this way..

```
DELETE c, o, od
 FROM customers as c
  JOIN orders as o ON c.id = o.customers_id
  JOIN order_detail as od ON o.id = od.orders_id
 WHERE c.id IN (66,67,68,90,85,81,80,78,76,74,71,118,113,110,149)
```

For more reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html